# How do financial analytics firms estimate the earnings from short sellers on an ETF or stock?

Tags: short-selling

I read on https://www.reuters.com/markets/europe/russia-etf-draws-meme-stock-like-trading-frenzy-2022-03-02/ ([mirror](https://archive.ph/ZYb6b)):

> The ETF's tumble has been a boon for bearish investors. RSX shorts are up $299 million in year-to-date mark-to-market profits, according to financial analytics firm S3 Partners.

How do financial analytics firms estimate the earnings from short sellers on an ETF or stock?

Comment: Probably just the product of the price change since December 31 times some estimate of the number of shares short during this period. So not very precise ...

Comment: Thanks, got it, makes sense.